# Need to pass values in dynamic request body in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, correlation, load-testing

Scenario: delete account

When i was recorded the script, I have 3 values in req body. Each values having one backend id

For example,

HTTP Method: POST

Request body is: (total values = 3)

2group:listvalue1:account_value_6 : 81990

2group:listvalue1:account_value_9 : 81394

2group:listvalue1:account_value_12 : 45623

While recording I have deleted the 1 st value.Done the recording.

Again when i try to record the script

I have "2 values" in request body

PS: Request body constantly changing.

HTTP Method: POST

Req body2:

2group:listvalue1:account_value_9 : 81394

2group:listvalue1:account_value_12 : 45623

Request body automatically changing depends upon the available data.

For this request how to do scripting.. could you tell me to fix this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Most probably those "backend ids" are present in one of the previous responses. So you need to implement so called ["correlation"](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

My expectation is that in order to do what you're trying to do (update or delete some content) you need to load this content first and the request which your browser sends has these content IDs somewhere in the response.

Check previous responses using View Results Tree listener and look for these dynamic values. Once you find them - use a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract them and store into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

Then replace recorded hard-coded values with the JMeter Variables from the Post-Processors.

More information: [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)